# Print Values In Array

Tags: perl, cgi

I can't seem to figure out how to print just some of the return values such as: `title`, `url`, `content`

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    use REST::Google;

    # set service to use
    REST::Google->service('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web');

    # provide a valid http referer
    REST::Google->http_referer('http://www.example.com');

    my $res = REST::Google->new(
            q => 'ice cream',
    );

    die "response status failure" if $res->responseStatus != 200;

    my $data = $res->responseData;

    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper( $data );

    my @results = $data->results;

    # CANT MAKE THIS WORK
    foreach my $r (@result) {
            print "\n";
            print $r->title;
            print $r->url;
            print $r->content;
    }
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. If you had, it would have told you the error: `Global symbol "@result" requires explicit package name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
use REST::Google;

# set service to use
REST::Google->service(
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web' );

# provide a valid http referer
REST::Google->http_referer( 'http://www.example.com' );

my $res = REST::Google->new( q => 'ice cream', );

die "response status failure" if $res->responseStatus != 200;

my $data    = $res->responseData;
my @results = @{ $data->{results} };

foreach my $r ( @results ) { 
    print "\n";
    print $r->{title};
    print $r->{url};
    print $r->{content};
}
```

A couple of problems here:

1) $data is not an object, so you can't treat it like an object.

$data->results would be the correct syntax if you're calling a method on an object. In this case $data is just a regular HASHREF, so the syntax is:

$data->{results}

2) $data->{results} is an ARRAYREF and not an ARRAY.  So, you need to de-reference it in order to get at the values.

Now, my @results = $data->{results} becomes:

my @results = @{ $data->{results} };

@{ ARRAYREF } is how you dereference the array.

3) As you're iterating over @results, you're once again using the object syntax.  However, the values of @results are also just plain HASHREFs.  So, $r->title becomes:

$r->{title}

Using a tool like Data::Dumper to inspect return values can be key in sorting this kind of thing out.  You may also want to look at [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPrinter), which is even sexier than Data::Dumper

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foreach my $r (@results) {
```

note the "s" -- if you put at the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

you will catch these things

Comment: OK "@result" is now "@results" use strict; and
use warnings; still don't work.

Comment: @Blnukem What does Data::Dumper print?